# How to access RGB values of the regions of an image given a 11x1 cell array where each cell contains the coordinates of each region?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I obtained the coordinate statistics from a binary version of the same image using regionprops. Code below

```
coordStats = regionprops(BW2, 'PixelList');
cellCoordStats = struct2cell(coordStats);
```

So I have the coordinates and my first question is now to access the coordinates for each region. My second questions is how to obtain the RGB values from the original image using these co ordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this directly with `regionprops`.  In short, it is possible to pass two images to `regionprops` - such as your original image and a BW image defining the regions.  The two images must be the same size, so for an RGB image this requires working with each channel separately.

```
% repeat for each channel
rStats = regionprops(BW2,I(:,:,1),'MeanIntensity',`PixelValues`,'PixelList');
```

To actually pull out the values you can use the original structure format, where the pixel coordinates can be accessed through `rStats(1).PixelList` through `rStats(end).PixelList` inclusive, and so on.  If you convert to a cell, it would be something like cellrStats{1,1} through cellrStats{1,n} (doublecheck the order but `PixelList` seems to go to the top of the struct regardless of order in which the options are called).

Comment: Thank you I'll try it that should save a lot of time

Comment: Is there a way to calculate the standard deviation also?

Comment: Not directly, but you can access `PixelValues` for each region and calculate it that way.  See [this Mathworks tutorial](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/image/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexprops.html)